# Get device screen resolution using WinRT API (c++)

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I want to know the screen resolution using WinRT API. I want the API to be available to both desktop and windows phone and to be able to call it from c++. I found out a solution using this:

```
DisplayInformation^ display = DisplayInformation::GetForCurrentView();
```

It requires me to be in a different thread and I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

That call won't necessarily tell you the screen resolution; it will tell you information about the size of your app's window. If you happen to be full-screen (always true on Phone; sometimes true on Desktop) then it will tell you the screen resolution of the monitor you are on.

You need to call it from the thread of one of the views in your application. Where are you trying to call it from?

Comment: This information is needed at a library level, and it will not be called by the app, it will be used internally. I know that this is the app window's information, but that was all I found. Do you know other solution?

Comment: It is possible using DirectX to get some information, but I don't know if that also requires being on the correct thread. I'm not familiar with DX, but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404606(v=vs.85).aspx) might help.